Flutter smoother circular of notched bottomAppBar
 

I made a bottomAppBar as shown in the above picture.
Here's My code:
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(35), topRight: Radius.circular(35)),
    child: BottomAppBar(
      elevation: 10,
      shadowColor: Colors.black,
      shape:
      const CircularNotchedRectangle(            
      ),
      notchMargin: 12,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
         //items of bottomAppBar
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

However, I want the smoother effect of notched part as shown in the picture below. 
How can I achieve this?



you can use animated_bottom_navigation_bar: any and if you want show icon with text then customize this.

@SachinKumawat Thanks for comment.But due to various considerations, I prefer not using packages.

you can download this package code then customize it OR see this package code for reference  you can implement.

This video may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ToqYMSnNhA

You may need to build a custom BottomAppBar.
In the link below you can find the solution to your question:
https://github.com/sardapv/NavBar-CurvedShape-flutter/blob/master/lib/main.dart
Also for implementing app bars with custom curves the article below is useful:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/custom-shaped-appbar-as-seen-in-the-bunny-search-app-6312d067485c
